# Python Selenium - ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: python, selenium

**EDIT**: accepted answer as it solved the issue itself.

I am trying to grab data from the following webpage [link](http://www.bundesliga.de/de/liga/statistik/spieltag/#)
in order to understand how selenium works (actually I am not interested in the data On the very last line I get an **ElementNotVisibleException error**. My code looks as follows:

```
path = mypath
url = 'http://www.bundesliga.de/de/liga/statistik/spieltag/'

#### SCRIPT TO TEST SELENIUM 

#### (0) Load driver 
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(path)  
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get(url)

#### (1) Define XPATHs
XPATH_MATCHDAY = '//*[contains(@class, "has-data")]'
XPATH_GAMES = "//*[contains(text(), 'mehr zum Spiel')]"
XPATH_TEAMSTATS = "//span[contains(text(), 'Teamstatistik')]"

### (2) Click links to Teamstats 

# Select Matchday 1
matchday = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(XPATH_MATCHDAY)[0] 
matchday.click()

# Select game one
game = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(XPATH_GAMES)[0]
game.click()

# Select teamstats tab (bottom of page)
teamstats = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(XPATH_TEAMSTATS)[0]
time.sleep(.5)
teamstats.click()
```

What the code is supposed to do:

- click on "1" in upper table "Spieltagsübersicht"
- click on "mehr zum Spiel" for first game
- click on tab "Teamstatistik" on second half of page.

However, although tab Teamstatistik is visible I get the error.

I have read about this error on stackoverflow quite intensively and also tried the following work around for the last lines. However, then I do get a TimeoutException.

```
teamstats = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"XPATH_TEAMSTATS")))
teamstats.click()
```

I have tried this with both PhantomJS and Chrome but was not able to fix this. I am a bit puzzled because the tab "Teamstatistik" I am trying to click on is always visible to me. I have tried if "teamstats.is_visible is available. But it is not. **(EDIT: now I tried .is_displayed and I get a FALSE). But how do I get it displayed? is this even possible?)**

To this end, I would be **grateful for any advice on**

- how to avoid the ElementNotVisibleException error / how to improve the code
- if selenium is best choice for this kind of website considering the alternatives is BeautifulSoup

Thanks for your support! This is actually my first post. So please be gentle ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. I have seen this post but my understanding is that workaround is in javascrip. So don't understand how this would work in python (if at all...).

Comment: By the way it's Java, but the most common reasons of `ElementNotVisibleException` happening listed there, check them and see which is yours.

Comment: I tried is_displayed and I get "FALSE" as response. So thanks for this. But still don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As target element located in invisible part of page, you might need to scroll down to make it visible:

```
teamstats = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(XPATH_TEAMSTATS)[0]
time.sleep(.5)
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', teamstats)
teamstats.click()
```

You can also try this simple way to scroll page down:

```
teamstats = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(XPATH_TEAMSTATS)[0]
time.sleep(.5)
teamstats.location_once_scrolled_into_view
teamstats.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this. And do get a different error message: 
'WebDriverException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive:...'

Comment: Hi Andersson, thanks for your answer. Your second solution first didn't work. Then I used Chrome and saw that site opens a cookie banner which is covering teamstats button. So on Chrome it does work if I remove the banner. On Phantom it still doesn't work. I took some screenshots (driver.save_screenshot) on every step and realized that link to matchday isn't even followed. Any idea how I can circumvent cookie banner and why this isn't working with phantom? Thanks!

Comment: Does issue still persist? Do I need to search for a solution?

Comment: On Chrome your solution now works. On Phantom still persists. For some reason the link to matchday (i.e. 2nd step) is not working. No error message...link is just not being followed. Any ideas?

Comment: I'll try to check it with `PhantomJS` on Monday as I have no possibility to do it on weekend... Let me know if you find solution before Monday.

Comment: thanks. I could not figure out why 'PhantomJS' behaves differently...any hint / idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: `PhantomJS` really sometimes behaves differently... mostly it behaves differently :) I tried to click `"mehr zum Spiel"` using `click()` as well as using `JS` and `Actions`, but it's not clickable for some reason ...

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help!